# not enough arguments in call to (_C2func_bcc_func_load)

Tags: go

I am getting an error *`not enough arguments in call to (_C2func_bcc_func_load)`*
when compiling Go.

Go Version used: **go version go1.19.1**

How can I resolve this error?  Would appreciate if anyone could help.

**Error Message:**

```
github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc
/home/jeremy/go/pkg/mod/github.com/iovisor/gobpf@v0.2.0/bcc/module.go:230:132: not enough arguments in call to (_C2func_bcc_func_load)
    have (unsafe.Pointer, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, *_Ctype_struct_bpf_insn, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, _Ctype_uint, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, _Ctype_uint, nil)
    want (unsafe.Pointer, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, *_Ctype_struct_bpf_insn, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, _Ctype_uint, _Ctype_int, *_Ctype_char, _Ctype_uint, *_Ctype_char, _Ctype_int)
```

[image]

Comment: paste the error message instead of image. People do not used to open image link most of time.

Answer (score 1):

I used latest recent commit which is compatible with `bcc-0.25.0`:

```
$ go list -m github.com/iovisor/gobpf@master
github.com/iovisor/gobpf v0.2.1-0.20221005153822-16120a1bf4d4
```

Then in your `go.mod`, use:

```
require github.com/iovisor/gobpf v0.2.1-0.20221005153822-16120a1bf4d4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your dependency library `github.com/iovisor` was broken. Try to check out their github to see if there are any issues, or just do something like `go get -u` to update your project dependencies to the latest versions (probably some new version have been already released and the problem is fixed). The version can also be restricted in your go.mod file, so you may want to change it there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the current version of gobpf I'm using is v0.2.0, which is the latest. But I still face the same error. Is there another way?

Comment: I am currently on the ebpf-training on GitHub (https://github.com/DataDog/ebpf-training/tree/main/workshop1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`gobpf@v0.2.0` is not compatible with `bcc-0.25.0`, but it works with `bcc-0.24.0`.

I checked out the code at the desired version:

```
git clone --branch v0.24.0 https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git
```

Then I followed the instructions to build it from source:

```bash
mkdir bcc/build; cd bcc/build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
cmake -DPYTHON_CMD=python3 .. # build python3 binding
pushd src/python/
make
sudo make install
popd
```

[This issue](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf/pull/311) has more information. There was a PR merged 12 days ago with a potential fix - it will be available in the next release of gobpf.